# one column coming from mysql and display it in to two column in html

Tags: php, html

I get the title from database. and I want to display it in to two column.
suppose in while loop print like

```html
<tr><td>first</td><td>second</td></tr>
<tr><td>third</td><td>fourth</td></tr>
```

```
 echo"<table border='1'>"; 
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
      {
       
            echo "<tr><td>".$row['title']."</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr>";
            
      }
      echo"</table>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can do a work around like below.

```
  echo"<table border='1'>"; 
  bool first = true;
  while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
  {
       if(first)
       {
            first = false;
            echo "<tr><td>".$row['title']."</td>";
       }
       else
       {
            echo "<td>$row['title']</td></tr>"
            first = true;
       }
  }
  echo"</table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 echo"<table border='1'>";

 $count = 0;

        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
            {

                $count ++;

                if ($count % 2 != 0) {
                    echo "<tr><td>".$row['title']."</td>";
                }

                else {
                    echo "<td>".$row['title']."</td></tr>"
                }
            }
      echo"</table>";
```